# Auto Increment in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Ok, so I started a To-DO-List project in order to learn some Android. I want to save every to-do task with SharedPreferences. 
Is there anything like SQL's Integer Primary Key for Android's SharedPreferences? Or should i add counters and "collectors" by myself?
I am also reading about HashMaps giving unique value to an object but I have never used it. I am new to programing as I said and I don't have enough experience to decide it by myself. Please don't be judgemental if this question seems stupid to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything like SQL's Integer Primary Key for Android's SharedPreferences?

No, sorry.

> Or should i add counters and "collectors" by myself?

I would use a SQLite database. Potentially, a to-do item has lots of bits of data (title, is-completed status, due date, priority, tags/labels, etc.). `SharedPreferences` is not designed for this.